# How do you make a JAR File change an XML file?

Tags: java, xml, jar

I am trying to rewrite an xml file via a jar file. Right now, the jar file can read off of the xml file, but it can't re-write it. Here is the code:

```js
public static void addMoney(int money) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(SaveData.class.getResourceAsStream("SaveData.xml"));
            Element udata = doc.getDocumentElement();
            udata.normalize();
            Node mnode = udata.getElementsByTagName("money").item(0);
            int mony = Integer.parseInt(mnode.getTextContent())+money;
            mnode.setTextContent(""+mony);
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("SaveData.xml"));
            transformer.transform(source, result);
        } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
```

I believe the error is in how I write the StreamResult result.